# Is there a standard way to document dependencies in a GNU Make package?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gnu-make

I'm wondering if there's a standard way to indicate the dependencies in Makefile-based C/C++ project. Should I mention it in INSTALL or README?

Comment: Ummm Dependencies go in a makefile.

Comment: @brianbeuning: Saying "project X depends on libY to build" does not go in a Makefile. Saying "executable X depends on the binary libY.so" does go in a Makefile.

Comment: @nneonneo Since your reply uses the word "depends" with two different meanings, you can understand my, and possibly others, confusion by this question.

Comment: internal dependencies belong in makefile, external dependencies can be managed by something like autoconf / automake etc.

Comment: Mention these in INSTALL or README. Perhaps mention the name of packages required (for a common distribution like Debian). Better yet, make a distribution package (eg a `.deb` file on Debian) of your program.

Comment: There is really no reason for putting dependencies in your Makefile, as your compiler would not compile if you do not have them, and so make will stop with an error, resulting in the same as having make checking dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

With most of the '.tar' files that I've opened, they document the dependencies in INSTALL or in README.  There doesn't appear to be a standard way to handle this.  The best makefiles that I've seen usually contain commented information regarding dependencies for the code in addition to historical hiccups in the build process.

In many other cases, the makefile has been auto-generated by a program like Automake, cmake, premake, python, perl, etc...

Auto-generated makefiles tend to be very difficult for a normal person to read.  Hand crafted makefiles tend to be a lot easier for us mortals to read.